# Can't close Tkinter window after selecting output folder for script

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function like this:

```
def ask_open_directory():
    root = Tk()
    # Prevent an actual interface from showing. We just want the file selection window
    root.withdraw()
    # Set focus on the window. This only works on MacOS
    os.system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "Python" to true' ''')
    # Open selector
    dirpath = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()

    # Doesn't do anything
    root.destroy()

    return dirpath
```

which is called first to select an input directory, and closes just fine, and then again right after, to select an output directory.

The script takes a couple of minutes to churn through all the data, and all the while, the Tkinter window for selecting output directory stays frozen until the script completes.

E.g. my script is organized like

```
def massive_function():
    input = custom_reader_function(input_location = ask_open_directory())
    output = ask_open_directory()

    lots of stuff happening
    finish
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve does not justify more than on `Tkinter.Tk()` instance.

I mean, you should remove `root = Tk()` , `root.withdraw()` and `root.destroy()` from your function. You should instantiate `Tkinter.Tk()` in your main program, not within individual functions.

Comment: Even with your proposed changes it doesn't make any difference. Except that I now get a white floating box because I'm missing `.withdraw()`

Comment: EDIT: I just found that `root.update()` in my script above gives the desired effect. Is it terribly wrong of me to do so, even if it gives the desired outcome? I guess I might incur some extra overhead by instantiating Tk for every file selection dialog?